# How to change Proxy system wide properly in Ubuntu 9.04?

Tags: ubuntu, proxy

I changed the proxy preferences in System->Preferences-> Network Proxy and applied "Apply System-wide". But after the change Firefox and other browsers goes through the proxy but not certain applications which i use to connect to internet.(like Songbird and other applets). Need a solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check in the apps whether the proxy settings are marked as "None", System Defaults, or Manual.

A lot of the apps have this default to None, which could be why they are not honouring the global settings you have applied.

Answer (score 0):

You change your proxy settings system wide. There isn't anything else you can do, system-wide, to achieve what you want. If some applications don't honor the setting, your best bet is a bug report.

Comment: @Manni -Abhinav also say same thing . Dont Copy

Comment: Well Manni said it first as per the timestamp :) I was probably on another window composing the answer !